# Redistribute linestring vertices to specified distance

Tags: geoprocessing, simplify, linestring, linear-referencing

I use a groundwater model program called GMS, and it has a very useful function "Redistribute vertices" ([more info](http://xmswiki.com/xms/GMS:Feature_Objects)). I use this function all the time to both simplify and provide *regular* spacings between points (vertices) in linestrings.

See this image from GMS where the black lines are original stream with irregular spacings, and the grey lines have redistributed vertices using 50.0 m
[image: from GMS]

I haven't seen the equivalent function anywhere else in the GIS-processing world (Esri, JTS, PostGIS, etc.). Redistribute vertices requires a specified spacing distance, whereas simplify-type functions use a tolerance and don't use a specified spacing. Does anyone know if there is something equivalent in either ArcGIS or open source GIS projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of processing is achieved using [linear referencing](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_linear_referencing). ArcGIS has a [number of tools](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_creating_and_editing_event_data) to work with linear referenced features, however for equidistant points it is often easier to create a small script to generate the points and then join them together as new lines.

In the opensource world most spatial databases have this funcitonality, as do spatial libraries such as [Shapely](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/manual.html#linear-referencing-methods) for Python.

Comment: The `linear referencing` keyword is a good start, but it looks like this will be a custom tool

Answer (score 2):

Since the version 2.x, PyQGIS has an has an `interpolate` function similar to that of [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) :

```py
for distance in xrange(0,lenght_line,20):
     point = line.interpolate(distance)
```

[image][image]

look at [How to create points in a specified distance along the line in QGIS？](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63201/how-to-create-points-in-a-specified-distance-along-the-line-in-qgis/63238#63238)

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I was able to redistribute the vertices to a specified distance in [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107999/how-do-you-modify-selected-geometry-with-a-function-in-qgis-python-console)

Answer (score 0):

Adapting my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107999/how-do-you-modify-selected-geometry-with-a-function-in-qgis-python-console?lq=1): First make ~/.qgis2/python/mytools.py :

```
from qgis.core import (QgsFeature, QgsGeometry,
                       QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry,
                       QgsField)
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.utils import iface
import math

def redistribute_geometry_vertices(geom,dist):
    mylen=geom.length()
    line=geom.asPolyline()
    return QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([geom.interpolate(i*float(dist)).asPoint() for i in range(int(math.ceil(mylen/dist)))])


def selection_update_geometry(userFunction, *args):
    """Redistribute the vertices along a polyline """
    layer = iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
    for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()
        newgeom=userFunction(geom,*args)
        layer.changeGeometry(feature.id(),newgeom)
```

Then select the layer, make it editable, select the features, then type this in the console:

```
import mytools
mytools.selection_update_geometry(mytools.redistribute_geometry_vertices,50)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function for PostGIS which uses [linear referencing functions](http://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Linear_Referencing) to redistribute vertices for [Multi]LineString and [Multi]Polygon geometries. For PostGIS 2.0 and earlier, `ST_LineInterpolatePoint` needs to be renamed to `ST_Line_Interpolate_Point`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_RedistributeVertices(geom geometry, distance double precision)
  RETURNS geometry AS $body$
DECLARE
  num_vert integer;
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN GeometryType(geom) ILIKE 'LineString%' THEN
      num_vert := round(ST_Length(geom) / distance);
      IF num_vert = 0 THEN
        num_vert := 1;
      END IF;
      RETURN ST_MakeLine(array_agg(
               ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, n::float8 / num_vert::float8)
             )) FROM generate_series(0, num_vert) AS n;
    WHEN GeometryType(geom) ILIKE 'Polygon%' AND ST_NRings(geom) = 1 THEN
      RETURN ST_MakePolygon(ST_RedistributeVertices(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), distance));
    WHEN GeometryType(geom) ILIKE 'Multi%' OR
         GeometryType(geom) ILIKE 'GeometryCollection%' THEN
      RETURN ST_Multi(ST_Collect(g))
        FROM (SELECT ST_RedistributeVertices((ST_Dump(geom)).geom, distance) AS g) AS f;
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unhandled geometry %', GeometryType(geom);
  END CASE;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

A warning on using a simple linear referencing technique is that the resulting vertices are not necessary spaced the specified `distance` apart. This would require a more complicated iterative function, which is beyond what you can comfortably do with PL/pgSQL.