# Creating Evenly Spaced Nodes/Lines or Set Spacing Rule in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0

I have written a Python script for ArcMap 10 that uses the x/y coords from a shapefile to create perpendicular transects to the existing line.  Since these shapefiles are actually rivers the lines are very curved.  In order to accurately represent the river's shape there are more points in the curves.  My problem is that the program I created takes all of these points to create multiple transects and in the curves it looks like a horrible mess because there are so many points.

Is there any way to create some kind of spacing rule where my program chooses evenly spaced nodes so I can avoid this messy overlap?

Comment: What is the purpose of the transects?

Comment: Mr. Huber, creating river transects has various functions in hydrology.  Eventually, we'll be able to accurately forecast river discharge based on length and width of the river.  My boss has simply asked me to create a program that creates equidistant transects perpendicular to river shapefiles from USGS. It's the whole setting up of equidistant points that is flummoxing me. Thanks

Comment: I understand the roles of transects and am not challenging what you're doing.  The question is, "why equidistant," given that you started off with irregularly spaced transects.  The way the question is worded strongly suggests you are choosing equidistant ones merely as a way to avoid clutter on a map rather than as part of a program of hydrological analysis.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying here and you certainly have a point.  When I showed my supervisor the fruits of my labor this was his request.  I can't say that choosing equidistant points makes the application any less valid, which is why I didn't dispute the request.

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6945/redistribute-linestring-vertices-to-specified-distance

Comment: Mr Wissler I have read your message because i am searching some tools on Arcgis 10.1. I want to create some transect along a river center line. Actually, May you help me. Is it possible to you to provide me your script. Thank you for paying attention. best regards

Answer (score 2):

This python tool splits a polyline into equal segments by a given length plus an eventual remainder.

http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=2552FE79-1422-2418-342E-6394F81D5E48

Comment: This is close to what I need but not exactly.  I may be able to steal portions of the script and employ it as an add on to mine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I had been looking for something similar for research I was doing awhile ago but just came across this.  If you are still looking for a solution I hope it helps:  http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000029000000.htm