# Creating points in specified distance along line using QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, distance, point-creation

I want to use QGIS creating points along the line, but in specified distance. I found two GRASS tools in SEXTANTE Toolbox：

- `v.to.points`
- `v.segment`

I tried `v.to.points`, setting the maximum distance between points in map units to 100 and got this：

[image: points along the line]

[image: close look]

The second photo showed a close look from the upper one. **The result was what I want, but I want to get less points**, but even I set the maximum distance to 1000, or 1000000, the result was the same.

I tried to use `v.segment`, but I had no file containing segment rules.

Underdark gave me some advice, and I tried **Densify geometries given an interval**. First it gave me a polyline shapefile the same as I input, and then I used **extract nodes** to try to get those points. But the result was the same as I got using `v.to.points`, no matter what I set the distance interval.

How can I create points along the line, and in specified distance？

Comment: Have a look at this, let us know   http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/generating-chainage-distance-nodes-in-qgis/

Comment: Thanks for giving me this helpful advice! If I want to use your script, have I to install python? or in the new version QGIS 2.0, does it already have this function built in it?

Comment: There is a plugin for this now in QGIS 2.0, called QChainage. Fetch the plugin and install it.

Comment: Note that the "Sextante" toolbox is called "Processing" in QGIS 2.2.0+ and the the Densify geometries given a an interval" is under the ProcessingToolbox/QGISGeoalgorithms/VectorGeometryTools menu.  Note that this denifies the geometry and doesn't remove vertices that are closer than the the chosen interval.

Comment: This worked for me: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LocatePoints/

Comment: This question is quite old by now. For QGIS 3+ this process is now native and **does not** requires additional plugins or codes. See recent answers below (may not be the most upvoted)

Answer (score 24):

There is now a plugin called QChainage that does exactly what you want.  You specify an interval distance and the plugin creates points along your line at the specified interval.

Comment: *Note that this won't capture your line nodes, so if you need them you will also need to use the geometry tool - extract nodes and append to your chainage points.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I think the information that you have appended here as a Comment would be better incorporated into your actual Answer by using the edit button beneath it.  You can do this with a Copy/Paste and the delete your comment by clicking the little cross next to it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! thank you! Not the same use case as the question, but I needed to find coordinates diff distances from a specified point, I used a diff plugin to draw the line, then used the layer it created with the plugin you mentioned and got what I needed! :D

Answer (score 23):

In the Python console:

- you can use the  [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely/1.2.17) module (as in [How to create equidistant points in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27102/how-to-create-equidistant-points-in-qgis)) with the function

  point = line.interpolate(currentdistance)
- The new Python API of the master version (1.9) has an equivalent command (as in [Generating chainage (distance) nodes in QGIS](http://nathanw.net/2012/08/05/generating-chainage-distance-nodes-in-qgis/)  of Nathan Woodrow)

  point = geom.interpolate(currentdistance)
- or you can use vector algebra and direction cosines (as in [PyQGIS: geometries, vectors, vector algebra or direction cosines, application examples](http://www.portailsig.org/content/pyqgis-des-geometries-des-vecteurs-de-l-algebre-vectorielle-ou-des-cosinus-directeurs-exempl), in French)

1) create a memory layer class (complete class (without attributes) at [crea_mem_layer.py](http://www.portailsig.org/content/creamemlayerpy))

```py
class Create_vlayer(object):
    '''creation of a virtual layer''' 
     def __init__(self,nom,type):
         self.type=type
         self.name = nom
         self.layer =  QgsVectorLayer(self.type, self.name , "memory")
         self.pr =self.layer.dataProvider() 
     def create_point(self,geometry):
         # add point to the layer
         self.seg = QgsFeature()
         self.seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(geometry))
         self.pr.addFeatures([self.seg])
         self.layer.updateExtents()
     @property
     def display_layer(self):
         #end of layer and display layer 
         QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([self.couche])
```

2) vector algebra functions (from [algèbre_vect_PyQGIS.py](http://www.portailsig.org/content/algebrevectpyqgispy))

```py
import math 
def mag(point):
    # magnitude of a vector
    return math.sqrt(point.x()**2 + point.y()**2)
def diff(point2, point1):
    # substraction betwen two vector
    return QgsPoint(point2.x()-point1.x(), point2.y() - point1.y())
def length(point1,point2):
    # with PyQGIS: sqrDist
    return math.sqrt(point1.sqrDist(point2))
```

3) direction cosines

```py
def dircos(point):
    cosa = point.x() / mag(point)
    cosb = point.y()/ mag(point)
    return cosa,cosb
```

4) process line or line segments

```py
def pairs(list):
    # list pairs iteration 
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
    yield list[i-1], list[i]

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
# interval between points
interval = 5 m
# create virtual layer
gen_pt  = Create_vlayer("mid5", "Point")

for elem in layer():
    line = elem.geometry()
    for seg_start, seg_end in pairs(line.asPolyline()):
       line_start = QgsPoint(seg_start)
       line_end = QgsPoint(seg_end)
       # mid point = vector coordinates [x2-x1,y2-y1]
       pointm =diff(line_end, line_start)
       # direction cosines of the segment
       cosa,cosb = dircos(pointm)
       # length of the segment
       lg = length(line_end, line_start)
       # generate and add points to the virtual layer 
       for i in range(interval,lg,interval):
           gen_pt.create_point(QgsPoint(line_start.x()  + (i * cosa), line_start.y() + (i*cosb)))

# display layer
gen_pt.display_layer
```

Results

polyline, equidistant point with Shapely or PyQGIS2, with direction cosines

[image: polyline][image: shapely][image: vector_algebra]

Then just adjust the interval

Comment: From looking at the junction, it looks like it keeps the pre-existing node points on the line, so it can't thin them to a resolution less than the vertices already on the line.  With complicated, curvy lines as in the OP, these procedures may not have much of an effect.

Comment: you can perfectly adapt the script.

Answer (score 16):

In QGIS 3 (at least in QGIS 3.10) there is a processing tool for that purpose: "Points along geometry"

[image]

Comment: Simplest answer. This should be the most upvoted answer nowadays...

Comment: I confirm tools are by now (QGIS 3.16) native in QGIS. For one example see [link](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-points-along-line).
Be just careful of the SRC of your data, the offset is expressed in this unit (degres, meters, ...)

Comment: As at QGIS 3.30, this is still the way to go...

Answer (score 13):

I've written a script that changes the Sextante Densify geometries tool to accept a certain distance. It's called **Densify geometries given an interval**.

After running Densify, you can extract the points using **Extract nodes** tool.

You can get it from [Github](https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-Sextante/blob/master/1.0.8/street-network-comparison/ftools/DensifyGeometriesInterval.py) and install instructions are on my [blog](http://anitagraser.com/2012/12/11/expanding-sextantes-ftools-toolbox/).

[image]

Comment: It appears this tool is now available in QGIS without the Sextante install (QGIS 2.18.7). I didn't see it in the menus, but found it as a QGIS geoalgorithm while searching in the Processing Toolbox.

Comment: This tool is available in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure if this is in the stable release, but in the sextante toolbox on 1.9 alpha under Geoalgorithims->Vector is the "Convert Lines to Points" option. Works a treat, be great if it added a field for distance along the line as well though.

Interesting it did add the NAME field from my vector layer though.

I tried getting that Python Script by Nathan Woodrow working, but I suck with python. And with code in general it seems.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to horse around with python scripts you can simply install and use the "Profile from line" plugin and ignore / delete the raster value column. The chainage will be whatever you set teh sampling interval to be.

Comment: In QGIS 2.2.0, I see a "Profile tool", "qProf" and "VoGIS-ProfilTool", but not a "Profile from line" tool.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time struggling with this issue, but eventually got more-or-less what I was looking for using QChainage. What I would like to share is something that may help others. When using the SAGA geoprocessing dissolve tool on the line, QChainage produces incorrect results. Use of a different dissolve tool causes it to work fine.