# Add line feature using bearing

Tags: qgis, line, bearing

QGIS 3.4.Is there a way using advanced digitizing to use a bearing, i.e. N 45° 15' 25" E as the angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS generally doesn't deal well with directions in degrees-minutes-seconds format, let alone quadrant bearing format (sometimes called azimuth and bearing).

This type of format is generally only used for US land surveys. The [Azimuth and Distance plugin](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-azimuth-distance-plugin) is the only tool in QGIS I know of that will accept land survey data in this format.

If this plugin doesn't do what you need, you'll probably have to convert your bearings to decimal degree. Try one of the methods discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291751/shapefile-from-heading-and-distance-directions-for-property-boundary), use an [online calculator](https://www.mathopenref.com/dmscalculator.html), or [use a spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213449/how-to-convert-degrees-minutes-seconds-angles-to-or-from-decimal-angle).

[This Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99606/how-to-enter-quadrant-bearings-into-copan-map-check) suggests that a free tool called "Copan" might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend working with [QGIS Python Plugins Repository](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/)

> "Geodesic Measure Tool" measures distances using the WGS 84 ellipsoid and includes the bearing or heading between points. It will even saves the measurements as a layer.
>
> Shape Tools is a collection of geodesic shapes and tools. Create ellipse, line of bearing, pie wedge, donut, arc wedge, polygon, star, ellipse rose, hypocyloid, polyfoil, epicycloid, and heart shapes. Tools include "XY to Line" tool, densify lines and polygons along geodesic paths, geodesic line break, geodesic measuring and create a measurement layer, geodesic scale, rotate, flip and translate tools, and digitize points at an azimuth & distance tools.

Comment: The Azimuth/Bearing input appears to only use decimal degrees.