# In QGIS Python console how can I calculate given the distance, bearing and initial point, the final point

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

In QGIS Python console, how can I calculate the location of a final point, given a distance and bearing from an initial point?
In PostGis I see that it is ST_Project, however I would like to do it with the QGIS python functionality.

In Postgis I used this:

`SELECT
utrancellid,
azimuth,
ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),
ST_MakePolygon(
ST_MakeLine(
ARRAY[
ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude)),
ST_AsText(ST_Project(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude)::geography, 100, radians((azimuth-30+360)%360))),
ST_AsText(ST_Project(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude)::geography, 100, radians((azimuth+30)%360))),
ST_AsText(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude))
]))
FROM
sector_location_csv;`

As you can see, ST_Project is a closed function, and was looking for something similar in QGIS, as I want to avoid trigonometric functions.

Comment: look at [How to create points based on the distance and bearing from a survey point?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76077/how-to-create-points-based-on-the-distance-and-bearing-from-a-survey-point/76175#76175)