# Change xy to lat long and vice versa

Tags: convert, latitude-longitude, xy

How could I get the lat,long of an object by knowing its xy values(in meters) from my vehicle (assuming it is(0,0) the center)?
For example my vehicle lat,long is 30,31 but it's xy values are always going to be (0,0). The object xy for example is (1.3,1.2) from the vehicle (in meters). How could I then change it to a lat and long?

Comment: See this: http://opencommons.uconn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005&context=nrme_articles and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255254/conversion-between-lat-lon-and-local-coordinate-system

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem is described here, maybe it helps you to get started, though it presumes a given direction and distance:

[How to create points based on the distance and bearing from a survey point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76077/how-to-create-points-based-on-the-distance-and-bearing-from-a-survey-point/76175#76175)

Comment: That does not solve the problem. On the link cited, there is no conversion from lat,long coordinates to xy values(in meters). It states a way to get an xy from an origin point, distance and angle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below URL:
http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/ConvertUTMNoOZ.HTM

Lat & lon of 30,31 will be in x & y as below:
**Y:** 307084.9
**X:** 3320469.3
**UTM:** 36

Comment: That, however does not help my case.

Comment: Abu bakr, check the new URL