# Convert x, y, z local points to WGS84 having only 3 coordinates known

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, geometry-conversion, cartesian

I have a set of (x, y, z) points on a local coordinates system cartesian plan.
For only 3 of these N points, I have the corresponding WGS84 coordinates (latitude, longitude and altitude).
How can I convert each of the other points in lat/lng coordinates?

EDIT:
Here an example of dataset:

| Point # | x, y, z | lat, lng, h |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 0, 0, 0 | 43.88072176381581, 11.072238294111774, 53 |
| P2 | 0, 12.24, 0 | 43.88099406334439, 11.072485923398222, 53 |
| P3 | 32.42, 6.79, 0 | 43.88080644977896, 11.072808964924704, 53 |
| P4 | -12.4, 1, 0.5 | ? |
| P5 | 55, 8.02, 0.2 | ? |
| P6 | 0.4, 3, 0 | ? |
| P7 | 1.03, -187.4, 5 | ? |

Comment: I think this is answered here, or at least it will point you to the logic and highlight a couple of issues: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255254/conversion-between-lat-lon-and-local-coordinate-system

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE, Asia. I do it in the following way: convert geographic to geocentric coordinates; find the parameters of a 3D similitude transformation from local cartesian to geocentric system; convert all points to geocentric and then all points to geographic coordinates. If you want to add the three trio of coordinates let me know and I will write an answer. Some Python code involved.

Comment: @LeighBettenay Thanks, I'll give a look.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I've edited the question, adding a sample dataset. No problem with Python code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it in the following way:

- Convert geodetic (3D) to geocentric coordinates;
- Find the parameters of a similitude transformation from local cartesian to geocentric system;
- Convert all points to geocentric and then all points to geodetic 3D coordinates.

For first and last steps I will use pyproj (2.6.1).
For the second step, I wasn't able to find an open source tool but a great math paper ([Huaien Zeng, Xing Fang, Guobin Chang and Ronghua Yang (2018) A dual quaternion algorithm of the Helmert transformation problem. Earth, Planets and Space (2018) 70:26](https://earth-planets-space.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40623-018-0792-x)).
I wrote a Python module to partial reproduce the algorithm presented there and published it in my github account (https://github.com/gabriel-de-luca/simil). You can download it to one directory of the Python interpreter Module Search Path, or in the same directory where you save the code that use it.

```py
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
import numpy as np
import simil

# local cartesian [x, y, z] Control points
local_ctrl_p = [[0, 0, 0],
                [0, 12.24, 0],
                [32.42, 6.79, 0]]

# geodetic [lat,lon,h] Control points
geodet_ctrl_p = [[43.88072176381581, 11.072238294111774, 53],
                 [43.88099406334439, 11.072485923398222, 53],
                 [43.88080644977896, 11.072808964924704, 53]]

# local cartesian [x, y, z] Other points
local_other_p = [[-12.4, 1, 0.5],
                 [55, 8.02, 0.2],
                 [0.4, 3, 0],
                 [1.03, -187.4, 5]]

# CRSes definitions
geodet_crs = CRS.from_epsg(4979) # Geodetic (lat,lon,h) system
geocent_crs = CRS.from_epsg(4978) # Geocentric (X,Y,Z) system

# pyproj transformer object from geodetic to geocentric
geodet_to_geocent = Transformer.from_crs(geodet_crs ,geocent_crs)

# convert geodetic control points to geocentric
geocent_ctrl_p = [geodet_to_geocent.transform(p[0],p[1],p[2])
                  for p in geodet_ctrl_p]

print(np.array(geocent_ctrl_p))
```

Returns the geodetic control points coordinates converted to geocentric:

```py
[[4518998.16289139  884318.52160765 4398585.26756981]
 [4518973.75937792  884334.02480144 4398607.07516105]
 [4518982.95389214  884362.27851799 4398592.04980611]]
```

Now let's find the parameters of the 3D linear transformation that better adjust source control points local cartesian coordinates to geocentric ones:

```py
# calculate Cartesian 3D similitude transformation parameters
# from Local Cartesian to Geocentric contol points
m_scalar, r_matrix, t_vector = simil.process(local_ctrl_p,
                                             geocent_ctrl_p)

print('M scalar = ', m_scalar)
print('R Matrix = \n', r_matrix)
print('T Vector = \n',  t_vector)
```

Returns:

```py
M scalar =  1.2808166135326584
R Matrix = 
 [[-0.00633138 -0.70681673  0.70736838]
 [ 0.98183953  0.12973377  0.13842067]
 [-0.18960762  0.69539863  0.69315922]]
T Vector = 
 [[4518990.78899169]
 [ 884323.63094196]
 [4398591.77207107]]
```

Control points coordinates must be multiplied by 1.28 to be adjusted to target coordinates. I usually don't have such scale factor (maybe the sample data provided is not real). I usually force the transformation to be adjusted with a fixed scale factor of 1:

```py
# same but force the scale factor to 1
m_scalar, r_matrix, t_vector = simil.process(local_ctrl_p,
                                             geocent_ctrl_p,
                                             scale=False,
                                             lambda_0=1)
print('M scalar = ', m_scalar)
print('R Matrix = \n', r_matrix)
print('T Vector = \n',  t_vector)
```

Returns:

```py
M scalar =  1.0
R Matrix = 
 [[-0.00634382 -0.7067637   0.70742126]
 [ 0.98183749  0.1297427   0.13842676]
 [-0.18961775  0.69545087  0.69310403]]
T Vector = 
 [[4518989.51051375]
 [ 884326.84158398]
 [4398592.43517149]]
```

Let's transform the source control points with these parameters. This is easier to me with coordinates instead of points so I transpose:

```py
# transpose source points to get coords
local_ctrl_coords = np.array(local_ctrl_p).T

# transform the control coordinates
transf_ctrl_coords = m_scalar * r_matrix @ local_ctrl_coords + t_vector

# transpose transformed control coordinates to get points
transf_ctrl_p = transf_ctrl_coords.T

print(transf_ctrl_p)
```

Returns:

```py
[[4518989.51051375  884326.84158398 4398592.43517149]
 [4518980.85972611  884328.42963463 4398600.94749011]
 [4518984.50592159  884359.55370846 4398591.00987537]]
```

There are (compensated) differences in meters. I hope the sample data provided is just not real at all. Now, transform all other points to geocentric and then to geodetic:

```py
# transform other points coordinates with same parameters
local_other_coords = np.array(local_other_p).T
transf_other_coords = m_scalar * r_matrix @ local_other_coords + t_vector
transf_other_p = transf_other_coords.T

# convert other points to geodetic
geocent_to_geodet = Transformer.from_crs(geocent_crs ,geodet_crs)
geodet_other_p = [geocent_to_geodet.transform(p[0],p[1],p[2])
                  for p in transf_other_p]

print(np.array(geodet_other_p))
```

Wich returns what we was looking for:

```py
[[43.88084931 11.07221498 53.49981423]
 [43.88075069 11.07304707 53.19980365]
 [43.88083637 11.07237519 52.9998092 ]
 [43.87918162 11.07175954 57.98771276]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! First of all, yes, the dataset is not real. Unfortunately, I need to code in C#, cause the project I'm working on is an Hololens 2 project. By the way, for the conversion between geodetic and ECEF coordinates (and back), I already wrote some functions on my own, so the lack of the pyproj library is not a problem. For the parameters estimation, I will take a look at your library to see if I could write some similar procedure in C#. Again, thanks!!

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. Glad to know that can be useful, make it open :-) You are welcome again!

Comment: Gabriel, sorry, I'm here again. :( I tried to convert your python script to C#, using Numpy for .NET, but it gives me a lot of errors, due to different functions in the library. Could you please help me in some way? I tried very hard to understand the maths behind this parameter estimation, but it's far too difficult for me to understand deeply how to do that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Asia, For some of the matrix operations I used numpy's einsum function, and I think the problem may be there. I think operations could be written through other less compact functions. I reproduced the whole paper algorithm by hand, in the sense of writing all the matrices for a simple case of three pairs of coordinates, doing all the operations corresponding to each element of each matrix, in order to understand it and translate it into python. I'm not a great developer or a great mathematician, but as far as I can help you, I will gladly do so.

Comment: Exactly, I'm struggling on the einsum function. I'm trying to find another way to write all the mathematical operations, without using it. For example, could you please help me understand this line of code (contained in _get_abc_matrices):
`matrix = np.einsum('i,ijk->jk', alpha_0, np.transpose(m1, (0,2,1)) @ m2)`

From numpy docs, I understood that the third parameter is an output variable... so why are you outputting the result in a matrix multiplication? How is it possible?
Maybe I misunderstood something... Thanks!

Comment: Since there are two subscripts (`i` and `ijk`), there are two operands for the einsum: the first is weights `alpha0` vector; and the second is, for the case of the `A` matrix (equation _(42)_ in the paper) computation, the product between transposed `W` matrix of the source quaternion points and the `Q` matrix of the target quaternions.

Comment: So, if I'm not wrong, I could write the same function this way: `np.tensordot(alpha_0, np.transpose(m1, (0,2,1)) @ m2, axes=([0],[0]))`. Is it right?

Comment: It's right, elements of first axis are the points (4x4 computed matrices) and their weights (a scalar), and we need to sum their product along that axis.

Comment: Great, with this syntax I'm able to write that. One last question: I've some problem with the function "_get_lambda_next". I think this should return a float value (but I'm obtaining an array)... is my assumption valid?

Comment: Yes, it is a scalar, the scale factor that is adjusted by iteration. Computed with the equation _(67)_ of the paper, where `r` quaternion is a 4x1 column vector (eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue of `D` matrix), transposed to 1x4, with `A`, `B` and `C` 4x4 matrices, and `b` and `c` scalars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122682/discussion-between-asia-and-gabriel-de-luca).

Comment: Hi Gabriel! How can I use more "control points" to exclude the ones how don't fit?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Asia, you can use any number of points in the same way, as a sorted list of source and target coordinates of all the control points that you have. You can use a list of weights too. The weight can be the inverse of the indetermination in the coordinates measurement. A point with an indetermination of 0.02 (meters if meters are your units) has a weight of 50. A point measured with an indetermination of 0.10 (m) has a weight of 10. The weights list is the alpha_0 parameter. Regards. Gabriel.

Comment: Thank you, but I have no idea how to determinate the weight of the points. These are given to me by the user and I have no idea of the precision at the beginning. I've read online that I can do this operation with more points and then calculate the residuals and eventually exclude the points with the too high residuals and do the transformation again. But I have no idea how to do this... does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Compute the parameters and transform all control points, compute the distances between expected and arrived coordinates. Get the average and standard deviation of the distances, and discard wich ones were one (or two or some threshold) standard deviations far away from the mean distance to expected destination coordinates.

Comment: Here an example:

            double[,] local_ctrl_p = new double[,] {
                {1, 1, 1},
                {2, 2, 2},
                {4, 4, 4},
                {8, 8, 8},
                {15, 14, 16},
            };

            double[,] geocent_ctrl_p = new double[,] {
                {2, 2, 2},
                {4, 4, 4},
                {8, 8, 8},
                {16, 16, 16},
                {32, 32, 32},
            };

The point {15, 14, 16} is the wrong one, I'd like to detect and exclude it from the local_ctrl_points. How can I do it?

Comment: Here the result of the transformation of the source control points with the obtained parameters:

DOUBLE
{ { 1.1424731182795638, 1.2849462365591389, 1.000000000000003 },
  { 2.076612903225801, 2.153225806451612, 2.0000000000000027 },
  { 3.9448924731182764, 3.889784946236559, 4.000000000000002 },
  { 7.681451612903227, 7.362903225806452, 8.0 },
  { 15.154569892473129, 14.30913978494624, 15.999999999999998 } }

I can't understand how should I use this to determinate which is the wrong point.
Thanks, again!

Comment: Hi, are you allowing the scale or not? allowing it I have: [[ 1.701  2.07   1.423]
 [ 3.845  4.043  3.695]
 [ 8.132  7.989  8.24 ]
 [16.708 15.882 17.329]
 [31.615 32.015 31.313]], not allowing scale I have: [[ 7.385  7.558  7.254]
 [ 8.39   8.483  8.319]
 [10.399 10.332 10.45 ]
 [14.419 14.032 14.711]
 [21.407 21.595 21.266]]

Comment: In any case, I need to analize the outputs. The coordinates are not usual, almost a geometric progressive line, with a little difference at the last point. The distribution of the points seems to be very influential in the transformation.

Comment: For the scaled output (the dataset doesn't have much sense without scaling), distances from expected to arrived coordinates are: [0.654 0.345 0.274 1.51  0.788], with a mean of 0.714 and standard deviation of 0.441. With a one standard deviation threshold we need to discard only [8 8 8] to [16 16 16] point. Without it distances are [0.411 0.072 0.607 0.125] with a mean of 0.304 and a standard deviation of 0.218. We can iterate the selection, removing second and third points. It is a problem, because the bad point was the last one. Seems to me like distribution of points is the problem.