# QGIS - tool to plot polygon from point with known bearings and distances

Tags: qgis, azimuth, cogo

Is there a tool that can convert a point dataset to a polygon based on some known parameters.

We will have

1- x,y

2. Azimuth

3.Distances in m for a- point in the direction of 2 (the azimuth) (200m), distance 180 degrees from 2 (25m), and distance -90/90 from the point (12m)

So the shapes will be something like this and be based on the point dataset.
[image]

We need to get the x,y for points lowercase a-d and then create a polygon based on these. If this is possible this can then be easily updated to have more points and create a better shape but the key question here is how can we create these points...

Is the only way to do this using spatial maths as in [Creating points based on distance and bearing from survey point using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76077/creating-points-based-on-distance-and-bearing-from-survey-point-using-qgis/76175)

Over the last year is there a plugin to achieve this?

Unfortunately, the Azimuth and Distance plugin works based on starting from a point and moving along that, whereas here I have multiple points and fixed dimensions.

The process to build a plugin/model to do this seems to be in http://www.portailsig.org/content/pyqgis-des-geometries-des-vecteurs-de-l-algebre-vectorielle-ou-des-cosinus-directeurs-exempl but I don't want to recreate the 'wheel' if I don't need to...

UPDATE
Unfortunately, my result with Kazuhito's reply is
[image]
and I get
2019-03-12T04:00:49     WARNING    Cannot zoom to selected feature(s) : No extent could be determined. Working in WGS 84.
[image]

Comment: Could you annotate your picture?

Comment: @Kazuhito I have improved the picture. We do actually have an additional piece of info which is the angle from A to B which is L1. L4/L3 will be +/- 90d of this and L2 is 180d. This gives us the shape we want. The final value is simply the direction from Pt 1 to 2 to 3. This shouldn't be needed to get a result for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can do this in two steps:

[Step 1] Create a series of points layer (Pt1, Pt2, ...)

[Step 2] Build the polygon at each point geometry from [Step 1].

Let me try to provide an answer for the [Step 2] part... building the ship ... if I can call them ships.

Tool is **Geometry by expression** in the Processing Toolbox >> Vector geometry.

```
combine(
 combine(
  tapered_buffer(make_line(project($geometry, 175, radians("Angle_A2B")), 
                           project($geometry, 200, radians("Angle_A2B"))), 
                 start_width:=24, end_width:=0),
  buffer(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 175, radians("Angle_A2B"))), 12)
  ),
 tapered_buffer(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 25, radians("Angle_A2B"+180))), 
                start_width:=24, end_width:=20)
)
```

The above expression combines three parts (bow, body, and stern of the ship).

---

Details about the above expression:

[The bow] ... ... a tapered buffer (175m~200m from the point A)

```
tapered_buffer(make_line(project($geometry, 175, radians("Angle_A2B")), 
                           project($geometry, 200, radians("Angle_A2B"))), 
                 start_width:=24, end_width:=0)
```

[The body] ... ... a 175m long x 2*12m wide buffer (the point A is at the rear end)

```
buffer(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 175, radians("Angle_A2B"))), 12)
```

[The stern] ... ... a tapered buffer (0m~25m toward the opposite side) The tail ends at 20m width. Please adjust as required.

```
tapered_buffer(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 25, radians("Angle_A2B"+180))), 
                    start_width:=24, end_width:=20)
```

Because `combine()` can take only two geometries, I used it twice to combine three geometries (combine(bow, body) and then with stern).

[image]

*NB - My expression in the picture is scaled by x10 times :)*

I did not answer to [Step 1] but `project($geometry, distance, azimuth())` will get you what you need.

---

**[Update]**

**"if the width is 14m on one side and 18m on the other (L3/L4) - how do we change the body calc to deal with this?"**

```
convex_hull(
  combine(
    make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 200, radians("Angle_A2B"))),
  combine(
  combine(
    offset_curve(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 175, radians("Angle_A2B"))), 14),
    offset_curve(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 175, radians("Angle_A2B"))), -18))
  ,
  combine(
    offset_curve(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 25, radians("Angle_A2B"+180))), 7),
    offset_curve(make_line($geometry, project($geometry, 25, radians("Angle_A2B"+180))), -9))
)))
```

[image]

Comment: brilliant - but I can't see any result. There is a table that's created but zoom to layer doesn't show anything. I will update the question with this. Can you send your test data to make sure I am not missing something simple?

Comment: I tried this but get the same result. Will send a test dataset shortly.

Comment: no need -it works now. I just had what you call "Angle_A2B" as "HDG" and off course making sure it was in UTM.

Comment: if the width is 14m on one side and 18m on the other (L3/L4) - how do we change the body calc to deal with this?