# Plot points around defined centroid using degrees and distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, centroids

I have a shapefile `plot_center` of plot centroid points (like picture below) and then I have a Excel table with trees which corresponds to plot centroid points by common field `ID`.

The excel table contains information about the trees measured in the area of each plot, however I do not have a coordinates of each tree. But what I do have is:

1. degrees: Direction measured from the center of the plot towards the tree, in grads. And the measurement is made starting from the North and in a clockwise direction.
2. distance: Distance, in meters, from the center of the plot to the tree.

I assume that using this information I should be able to plot the trees around the corresponding plot centroid, however I could not figure out how to do that. Seems a little complex! A solution in Python would also be useful!

Lets say I need to plot trees from Excel table around point No. 1613. I have a degrees  and distance.

[image]

[image]

Let's take the plot No. 1613 and first row on the table. Graphically that would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Is this about symbology or changing the geometry?

Comment: Neither, I just need to create new shapefile with trees from Excel, around the corresponding plot centroid using degrees and distance.

Comment: So, you want to change the geometry.

Comment: Have you tried the `translate geometry` tool with data defined override?

Comment: I added a graph how I have imagined the process. I just need to do that in either Qgis or python.

Comment: As I said above: Have you tried the `translate geometry` tool?

Comment: No, I have not, but how can I add there the excel table and link the points and trees with the ID field?

Comment: try the Join in QGIS : https://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/performing_table_joins.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Join the tables using "Join attributes by field value". The plot points as input layer, the trees table as input layer 2, join type "one to many". I saved the excel to csv and drag-dropped the csv in QGIS.
2. Geometry by expression. "Output geometry type Point", expression  `project( $geometry, "distance", radians("degrees"))`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the `pyproj.geod` module to determine the coordinates of the trees...

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/geod.html#pyproj.Geod.fwd

To quote from the docs for `geod.fwd()`:

> Determine longitudes, latitudes and back azimuths of terminus points given longitudes and latitudes of initial points, plus forward azimuths and distances.

... here's a quick example how it would work:

```py
from pyproj import CRS

lons, lats = [45, 45.0003, 45.0005], [45, 45.0003, 45]

trees = (dict(d=[10, 10, 10, 10, 10], az=[45, 90, 135, 180, 275]),
         dict(d=[10, 10, 10, 10, 10], az=[20, 40, 60, 80, 100]),
         dict(d=[10, 10, 10, 10, 10], az=[30, 50, 120, 165, 273]))

geod = CRS.from_epsg(4326).get_geod()

tree_coordinates = []
for lon, lat, tree in zip(lons, lats, trees):
    ntrees = len(tree["d"])
    pts = geod.fwd([lon]*ntrees, [lat]*ntrees, tree["az"], tree["d"])
    tree_coordinates.append(dict(lon=pts[0], lat=pts[1]))
```

... and to make sure that it does the right thing, here's a quick plot (using [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps))

```py
from eomaps import Maps

m = Maps(Maps.CRS.Orthographic(45, 45))
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.set_data(None, lons, lats)
m.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=10, n=100)
m.plot_map(fc="none", ec="k", ls="--")

m.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=.5)
m.plot_map(fc="k")

for t in tree_coordinates:
    vals = list(range(len(t["lon"])))
    
    m2 = m.new_layer()
    m2.set_data(vals, t["lon"], t["lat"])
    m2.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=1, n=100)
    m2.plot_map(cmap="Greens", set_extent=False, ec="k")
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement this with dataframe. I tried lons, lats = list(point.x), list(point.y), trees = gdf[['Distance', 'degree']] and when printing ntrees = len(trees["Distance"]) I get TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: you don't need to stick to the example-structure! just use `geod.fwd(longitudes, latitutdes, angles, distances)` and you'll get the coordinates of the trees!  (it should be possible to use dataframe-columns... no need to convert to list)

Comment: if you need further help with this, please provide a copy-paste-able code-snippet to reproduce your dataframe!

Answer (score 0):

Used this solution https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76115/178904 and did it in 4 Python lines:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf['C'] = np.sin(np.deg2rad(gdf['azimuth']))*gdf['distance']
gdf['D'] = np.cos(np.deg2rad(gdf['azimuth']))*gdf['distance']

gdf['x1'] = gdf['CoorX'] + gdf['C']
gdf['y1'] = gdf['CoorY'] + gdf['D']
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is not a QGIS one then