# Plotting sample stations upon contour line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, contour, markers

I need to create point sample stations on two contour lines (-10m and -20m). What I'm intending to do is, put markers (circle with stroke) on the contour lines, with equal distance from one point to another. I'm also willing to add a specific amount of station (30) for a specific amount of area in the map.

Although I have been able to make contour of both elevation mentioned, I don't know how to plot the sample stations as markers on map. How can I do this? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create points along a line.

The easiest is probably to use the **"Points along Geometry"** tool, which is found under the "processing tool box" (look for a gear icon).

If you want to find out more, please refer to this similar post: 
[Creating points in specified distance along line using QGIS？](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63201/creating-points-in-specified-distance-along-line-using-qgis)

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post. I have tried qchainange and point geometry tool. But i'm still facing difficulties, rather than the point being plotted upon the contour, it's being plotted all over the map. Here's an screenshot of the task i'm doing [imgur] (imgur.com/a/rdJs09B).

Comment: The screenshot show that `Chainage every` is set to 30 *degrees*, which is an enormous value. Mayeb you wanted to use 30 *meters* ?

Comment: i have set the chains to kilometers this time, however the problem persists. it's still all over the map rather than the specific contour i want. do you i should do anything with the attribute table, maybe write a command which would plot points only in -10m contour ? here's the screenshot: [imgur] (imgur.com/a/OoFD0ho)